# Using Selenium Java I want to automate a table that contains a price list and a price calculator

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testng

**Problem:** Using Selenium Java I want to automate a table that contains a price list and a price calculator

**Another little problem:** I can't click on the "Analysis" (Filter) button, because I have to double-click, which I could do in this case
[image]

**What I want:** I'm trying to find a method so that when I run the program, the program will click on another analysis (on another + button) Now with the help of a selector, I can only click on the first (+). But I want each time, the program to test, randomly other analyzes (other buttons +).

**What I do**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='footable_501']/thead/tr[2]/th[1]")
    WebElement analizaSort;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='footable_501']/thead/tr[2]/th[2]")
    WebElement pretSort;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='calculator']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]")
    WebElement total;


    public void checkCalculator()
    {
        add.click();
        add2.click();

    }

    public void checkFilter()
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)"); //Scroll vertically down by 1000 pixels
        analizaSort.click();
        analizaSort.click();
        pretSort.click();
    }
```

Link: https://www.poliana.ro/analize-preturi/

Comment: Can you check your provided link? It is showing authorization alert

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. I put the correct link. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added below the code to click on a random analyze and to calculate the total:

```
@FindBy(css = "th.footable-sortable[class*='pret']") // css locator is faster than xpath
WebElement pretSort;

@FindBy(css = "th.footable-sortable[class*='analiza']")
WebElement analizaSort;

@FindBy(css = "tr[class*='row'] td[class*='pret']")
List<WebElement> analyzePriceList;

@FindBy(css = "#calculator .total .right")
WebElement total;

public void checkCalculator() {
    int elementListSize = analyzePriceList.size();
    assertTrue("No analyze was found in the table", elementListSize != 0); // replace here with the specific of your testing framework
    
    int elementIndex = getRandomNumber(elementListSize - 1);
    scrollElementToTheMiddle(analyzePriceList.get(elementIndex));
    int expectedTotal = getTextAsInt(analyzePriceList.get(elementIndex));
    analyzePriceList.get(elementIndex).click();

    String totalAsString = total.getText().replace("lei", "");
    int actualTotal = getInt(totalAsString);
    
    assertEquals(expectedTotal, actualTotal);
}

public void checkFilter() {
    scrollElementToTheMiddle(analizaSort);
    analizaSort.click();
    analizaSort.click(); // if you need double click, please see the below method
    pretSort.click();
}

private void doubleClick(WebElement element) {
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.doubleClick(element).build().perform();
}

private int getTextAsInt(WebElement element) {
    String text = element.getText();
    
    return getInt(text);
}

private int getInt(String text) {
    assertTrue("The " + text + " text was expected to be numeric", isNumeric(text)); // replace here with the specific of your testing framework
    
    return Integer.parseInt(text);
}

private boolean isNumeric(String possibleNumberAsString) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\n");

    if (possibleNumberAsString == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return pattern.matcher(possibleNumberAsString.trim()).matches();
}

private int getRandomNumber(int maximum) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, maximum);
}

private void scrollElementToTheMiddle(WebElement element) {
    String scrollElementIntoMiddle = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);"
            + "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;"
            + "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scrollElementIntoMiddle, element);
}
```

Comment: @Uti Anm do you need more help with this? have you tried the solution?